# why could not add comment in generate column in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

when I try to add commnent on generate column in MySQL 5.7:

```
An error occurred when trying to change the field 'real_people_real_revenue' via

ALTER TABLE `report_summary` CHANGE `real_people_real_revenue` `real_people_real_revenue` BIGINT(20)
NULL
COMMENT 'q'
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (((`real_people_revenue` - `system_reward`) - `expect_reward`)) STORED

MySQL said: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GENERATED ALWAYS AS (((`real_people_revenue` - `system_reward`) - `expect_reward' at line 4
```

could I add comment on gernete column in MySQL 5.7?

Comment: MySQL is picky about what order clauses come in.

Comment: also too many brackets - `(real_people_revenue - system_reward - expect_reward)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

add comment like this:

```
alter table report_summary modify column real_people_real_revenue bigint comment 'new comment';
```

Comment: yes, this maps to the [column_defination](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) where the `COMMENT` comes after `GENERATED ALWAYS` and before `reference_definition`.

Comment: You've taken out the `GENERATED ALWAYS AS`... where does it fit in now?